# Error in my "case" but I don't know what the problem

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

can anyone help me with this error message? I keep getting that there is an error in my "case" but I don't know what the problem is, so I googled the CASE syntax is correct

```
SELECT 
    AccountID,
    Numero_material 
    
    CASE WHEN Numero_material ='4001267' or Numero_material ='4009269'
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
    END AS Template_email

FROM jornada_hipertensao_V3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a comma missing in the third line:

```
SELECT 
    AccountID,
    Numero_material,
    CASE WHEN Numero_material ='4001267' or Numero_material ='4009269'
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
    END AS Template_email

FROM jornada_hipertensao_V3
```

Comment: thank youuuu!! @zuzannamj